# Should I use AsyncController at ASP.NET MVC 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, asp.net-mvc-4, async-await

This class has this description:

```
Provided for backward compatibility with ASP.NET MVC 3.
```

And the source is just:

```
public abstract class AsyncController : Controller
{
}
```

I can´t find any documentation about deprecation of this class at MSDN. Should I replace uses of AsyncController to Controller?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

> Should I use AsyncController at ASP.NET MVC 4?

No.

> Should I replace uses of AsyncController to Controller?

Yes, asynchronous actions are implemented in new way in asp.net-mvc 4, using [Task Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx)

> The ASP.NET MVC 4 Controller class in combination .NET 4.5  enables
>   you to write asynchronous action methods that return an object of type
>   Task. The .NET Framework 4 introduced an asynchronous
>   programming concept referred to as a Task and ASP.NET MVC 4 supports
>   Task. Tasks are represented by the Task  type and related types in the
>   System.Threading.Tasks namespace. The .NET Framework 4.5 builds on
>   this asynchronous support with  the await and async keywords that make
>   working with Task objects much less complex than previous asynchronous
>   approaches.  The await keyword is syntactical shorthand for indicating
>   that a piece of code should asynchronously wait on some other piece of
>   code. The async keyword represents a hint that you can use to mark
>   methods as task-based asynchronous methods.  The combination of await,
>   async, and the Task object makes it much easier for you to write
>   asynchronous code in .NET 4.5. The new model for asynchronous methods
>   is called the Task-based Asynchronous Pattern (TAP). This tutorial
>   assumes you have some familiarity with asynchronous programing using 
>   await  and async keywords and the Task namespace.

More reading at [Using Asynchronous Methods in ASP.NET MVC 4](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4)

Comment: So, the answer is "no"? Right? I shouldn´t use AsyncController. I should use Controller since "The ASP.NET MVC 4 Controller class in combination .NET 4.5 enables you to write asynchronous action methods that return an object of type Task"

Comment: Yes, answer is "no". If using .NET 4.5, using Tasks is simpler and better way than subclassing AsyncController

Comment: If you don't need a callback, [Parallel.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609(v=vs.110).aspx) seems simpler.

Comment: TPL poses new problems with thread pools and you should look out for scalability issues such as thread starvation