# Wrapped ASP.NET MVC Controller does not support Async action method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

I'm working on an ASP.Net MVC 4 Project.All of Controllers in this project is wrapped into a custom controller like this:

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller{

    protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext){

    }

    protected override IActionInvoker CreateActionInvoker(){
    return new WebControllerActionInvoker();
    }
}
```

Everything is OK. But when I want to use async modifier in an async action method, action method does not work correctly and return this message
in view

> System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult]

now what should I do to fix this problem?

Edit:action method sample

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Details(string id) { 
var user = await userService.FindByIdAsync(id); 
return View(user);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'use async modifier in async method'?

Comment: like this `public async Task<ActionResult> Index()`

Comment: Could you provide action code sample please. Ensure that you are using `await`.

Comment: `public async Task<ActionResult> Details(string id) { var user = await userService.FindByIdAsync(id); return View(user);}`

Comment: @codeWorm, action looks okay to me. are you sure that you are not overriding default execution behaviour in your `BaseController`? **System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult]** most likely means that task is not being awaited.

Answer (score 3):

You should derive from `AsyncController` to get it working:

> Instead of deriving the controller from Controller, derive it from
>   AsyncController. Controllers that derive from AsyncController enable
>   ASP.NET to process asynchronous requests, and they can still service
>   synchronous action methods.

`Controller` by default cannot handle asynchronous actions.

EDIT:

Since above method is for .NET 4 and it seems it is deprecated, you can find another approach [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4).

Comment: that does not work in mvc 4. take a look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13721571/should-i-use-asynccontroller-at-asp-net-mvc-4)

Comment: [official documentation](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4) says different:  Controller class in combination .NET 4.5  enables you to write asynchronous action methods that return an object of type  Task<ActionResult>.

Comment: @ieaglle Yes, this is new, easier way of creating asynchronous methods.

Comment: @Kamo when I use Controller class the relevant view is displayed correctly but when I use BaseController instead, the view just display a message like this System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult]